# How do you convert cm values to inches and replace the text "cm" to "in"? Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to recreate a garment measurement chart I've seen, but in pure Javascript.  I'm having trouble figuring out how to grab the number value in innerhtml and multiply/divide it by * 2.54. Additionally, I'd like to add "cm" or "in" at the end of the number to indicate the measurement system.

https://jsfiddle.net/kud8sj7w/5/

```
<div id="xs-sizes">
        <li class="measurement" style="left: 15%; top: 33%;">
            63.5
        </li><li class="measurement" style="left: 48%; top: 16%;">
            43.5
        </li><li class="measurement" style="left: 48%; top: 79%;">
            50.5
        </li><li class="measurement" style="left: 48%; top: 50%;">
            43
        </li><li class="measurement" style="left: 83%; top: 62%;">
            64.5
        </li>
```

```
 function convert() {
      var measurements = document.getElementsByClassName("measurement");
      
       for(var i = 0; i < measurements.length; i++){
       
          measurements[i].innerHTML = valNum * 2.54;
       }
  }
```

Comment: `valNum` is undefined, isn't it? What do you put in it? What about `measurements[i].textContent /= 2.54;`

Comment: @Déjàvu yeah it's undefined.

Comment: Since you intend to convert cm to in and back, you have to keep the current status somewhere in a var (cm or in), initially set to 'cm'. So that when you convert you know from what to what you have to convert... (plus there could be some precision issues, but... let's start with that, you make another question later if you need - one problem at a  time :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1hw6kmaf/

Comment: @Thomas your code is so clean 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to store the current state to know whether you need to convert or not. In your case, initially 'CM'

```js
 let cur_measurement = 'CM';

 function convert() {
   let measurements = document.getElementsByClassName("measurement");
   let CM = document.querySelector('input[value="CM"]');
   let IN = document.querySelector('input[value="IN"]');
   
   let ratio = 0;
   if(CM.checked && cur_measurement != 'CM'){
        ratio = 2.54;
      cur_measurement = 'CM';
   } else if (IN.checked && cur_measurement != 'IN' ){
        ratio = 1/2.54;
      cur_measurement = 'IN';
   }

   for (var i = 0; i < measurements.length; i++) {
        let cur_val = parseFloat(measurements[i].innerText);
        measurements[i].innerText = Math.round(cur_val * ratio * 10) / 10;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

So for `measurements[i].innerHTML = valNum * 2.54;`, `valNum` is undefined. Look at `convert()` there's no parameters. When it's called it multiplies by `valNum` which is `undefined`.

Think about what `valNum` should equal to or what `2.54` should be operating on. I hope that helps. Also to string the `cm/unit`, you can just concatenate but get the result first.